# Cancel NSOperations based on position in TableView/CollectionVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsoperation

Suppose I have a table view or a collection view. In the cells I would need to load certain content (eg. an Image). I can get the content from local storage (if it has been saved there) or from the internet. Either way loading the content takes a while (500 kB Image).

The best way to do this is to create an NSOperation that will load in the background and then call a delegate when it finishes.

But suppose the user enters the table view / collection view and the queues start to get the first set of content (1-10) but then the user scroll quickly right to the end (visible cells 100-110) what should I do? The start-download operation happens when the cell is presented (cellForRowAtIndexPath) so I need to wait for everything to download until the user (who is now at the end of the tableView) sees content.
I tried creating a queue on each cell and cancelling that in prepareForReuse, but that crashes the app.

Anyway if the user is in a section of the tableview and content is downloading, but not shown yet, and scrolls further causing the download to be cancelled and then returns. Then he will need to download the first half of the image again, which is not good on limited data plans.

What is the best way to handle such a situation?

Comment: First I would definitely do thumbnails instead of 500 kB images for just a tableView. How big are the cells? A normal sized cell on an iPhone you can get ~ 6 cells. Why are you forcing them to load 3 MB of data just for one screen of rows? Load thumbnails to speed things up. Only commit to a larger image (500 kB) if they're going to the actual screen detail.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical discussion. Of course I would use thumbnails if at all possible for such an app.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your controller class adopt the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, which will allow you to inject custom code into `–tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` (called for you by the table view when a cell is to be displayed). In it you could calculate that because of the screen size, only rows within `k` indices of any row being shown could possibly be visible; thus, in this method call, cancel all the load operations associated with rows outside that range (relative to `indexPath` argument).

Comment: That would mean canceling the download operation queue and immediately after adding the downloads for the "on screen" cells ? Wouldn't this cause some operations to be cancel right before they are added again to the queue? Of should I start the operations manually instead of using an op queue?

Comment: Assuming that you are scrolling continuously in one direction (which i think is inescapable) then you won't have this problem. Consider: Suppose you are starting at index 0, formatted as an indexPath, and you can only fit 5 rows on the table at once (i forget the precise number). This means that as you scroll right, it will say "trying to show row 6" and so will call this; now you designate that everything more than 5 away in either direction will stop downloading: that includes 1, which is OK because it is being taken off screen; and everything > 11, which is OK because they never started

Comment: @Quintana Instead of keeping track of k indicies, I think you should just use an NSDictionary to be honest. You can have multiple k depending on if more screen sizes are introduced. You can have an NSDictionary of <IndexPath.row, NSOperation>. If your operation comes back, remove it from the Dictionary. Otherwise in your `didEndDisplayingCell` callback you can cancel the operation for that index.

Comment: @LyricalPanda good point. Although if you do that, don't forget to store `@(IndexPath.row)` as your dictionary keys, because `IndexPath.row` returns an NSInteger, which needs to be converted to an NSNumber to store in a dictionary. Its literal value can be retrieved with `-integerValue`.